# Extracting rows on basis of specific column values in R

Tags: python, r, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataframe that contains various fields. An instance being:

```
Protein Code Sequence CODON
XYZ    L    AATTGCTA    MET
ABC    K    ATTGCTA    MET-2
JKL    B    GCTTATA     LYS-2
```

I want to extract information of all the elements in which the column CODON ends with "-2". Like in this case i get :

```
ABC    K    ATTGCTA    MET-2
JKL    B    GCTTATA     LYS-2
```

Please suggest the answer.

I used :

```
od_lig <- filter(odor_lig, CODON== "$-2")
```

But I got blank data.

Comment: Try `filter(odor_lig, stringr::str_detect(CODON, "-2$"))`

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
subset(df, grepl("\\-2", CODON))
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Protein = c("XYZ", "ABC", "JKL"), Code = c("L", 
"K", "B"), Sequence = c("AATTGCTA", "ATTGCTA", "GCTTATA"), CODON = c("MET", 
"MET-2", "LYS-2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```